# AdminLTE plugins Rails 6 Webpacker precompile in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker, adminlte

Trying to use [AdminLTE 3](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE) plugins in Rails 6 with Webpacker. I need to import [select2.css](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/tree/master/plugins/select2/css), but it fails in the Production build.

This plugin works correctly in development:

```
# app/javascript/stylesheets/admin.scss

@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min";
@import "~admin-lte/plugins/select2/css/select2.min";
```

but in production I got the following error:

```
 @import "~admin-lte/plugins/select2/css/select2.min";
           ^
   File to import not found or unreadable: ~admin-lte/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.
```

What am I missing in Webpacker precompile configuration?
Thanks

*Note:* production deployment in Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Importing `select2` w/o `admin-lte` solves the problem:

```
# app/javascript/stylesheets/admin.scss

@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min";
@import "~select2/dist/css/select2.min";
```